# Why can I not access an inner class in Java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am having a trouble using nested classes in Java, does anyone know why Java does not allow me to do it?

```
public class A{
    private class B{
        public B(){
            System.out.println("class B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         A a = new A();
         B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use inner classes in first place :). Do you really need it?

Comment: @libik:  There's nothing wrong with inner classes, but like most features of a language, you can abuse it.

Comment: Just a thought... always include the type or error that you are experiencing as well when posting questions.

Comment: @Makoto - well there is nothing wrong with `instanceof` or `singleton` pattern, but it usually means bad design, if you need it.

Answer (score 8):

Because you are trying to access a non-static inner-class from a static method.

The 1st solution will be to change your inner-class `B` to `static`:

```
public class A{
    private static class B {
        public B() {
            System.out.println("class B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         A a = new A();
         B b = new B();
    }
}
```

a `static` inner-class is accessible from anywhere, but a non-static one, requires an instance of your container class.

Another solution will be:

```
A a = new A();
B b = a.new B();
```

This will give you a better understanding of how inner classes work in Java: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077411/core-java/inner-classes.html

Answer (score 7):

```
A a = new A();
B b = a.new B();
```

can solve your problem

You used private inner class.How can you get instance outside the A class?

```
public class JustForShow {
    public class JustTry{

        public JustTry() {
            System.out.println("Initialized");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JustForShow jfs = new JustForShow();
        JustTry jt = jfs.new JustTry();
    }
}
```

Comment: Reread your code there matey.

Comment: This is valid java code that does indeed create an instance of B.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to access a non-static membor from a static method. To solve that, you have two options:

1. Change your class `B` to be static, so add the `static` keyword in the class definition, like this:

   ```
   public static class B { // ...
   ```
2. Change your main method, and use the created instance `a` to create `B`, like this:

   ```
   B b = a.new B();
   ```

If `B` doesn't use any non-static resources of class `A`, I would recommend to use the first method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     A a = new A();
     A.B b = a.new B();
}
```